# При восстановлении размера формы, элементы грузятся вконце

Tags: c#, winforms, opacity

Имеется 2 формы, одна из которых является формой заполненной одной картинкой (Form3), вторая (Form1) - мейн. При нажатии на кнопку в Form1 - мейн сворачивается таким образом, открывая F3:

```
Form3 formButton = new Form3();
formButton.Owner = this;
formButton.Show();
formButton.Opacity = 0;
while (this.Opacity != 0)
{
    Thread.Sleep(30);
    this.Opacity -= 0.1;
}


while (formButton.Opacity != 1)
{
    Thread.Sleep(30);
    formButton.Opacity += 0.1;
}
```

Проблема в том, что при появлении, пока выполняется цикл, на форме нет ничего, кроме дырок от элементов. Сами элементы загружаются только когда программа выходит из цикла.

Вот обратное возвращение мейна:

```
formMain.Opacity = 0;
formMain.Show();
while (formMain.Opacity != 1)
{
    Thread.Sleep(30);
    formMain.Opacity += 0.1;
}
while (this.Opacity != 0)
{
    Thread.Sleep(30);
    this.Opacity -= 0.1;
}
```

Может есть у кого простое или не очень решение этой проблемы. Хотелось бы чтобы весь интерфейс появлялся плавно, а не только форма, и по окончанию мгновенно элементы.

Comment: Мне кажется тут немного не так надо поступать. Поведайте, какие цели преследуете. Просто создание 2 окон весьма редко бывает оправдано, обычно вешают диалог или вообще внутри одной формы весь бизнес строят. А тут получается вы окну задали владельца, а владельца же пытаетесь скрыть, тогда зачем задавали?

Comment: Необходимо, чтобы программа, пряталась с экрана, и оставляла за собой хвостик, за который её можно открыть. Я думал, как реализовать это в одной форме, но знаний не хватило. Единственное представление решения для одной формы не подходит для владельцев 2ух и более мониторов(

Comment: А делать что она должна во время спрятанного/открытого состояния?

Comment: Ничего и в спрятанном и в открытом состоянии. Это просто Важные номера телефонов для компании, для экстренной связи.

Comment: Реализовал тоже самое через одну форму, но проблема осталась.

Comment: Это winForms как понимаю? Инициализация компонентов в конструкторе же сидит, проверь. вот тут Form3 formButton = new Form3(); уже должны быть проинициализированы. Однако, отрисовка не работает, .т.к. поток занят. Выозвай в цикле принудительную отрисовку. Либо opasity меняй таймером (более правильный вариант),т.е. не в основном потоке.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Как уже сказано в комментариях, циклы `while` c `Thread.Sleep` внутри работают в потоке GUI, что приводит к "замерзанию" формы.

Давайте сделаем это с помощью таймера.

Таймеров в дотнете имеется несколько штук разных, нам понадобится тот, который в пространстве имён `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` - он может работать с контролами на форме напрямую, так как его событие `Tick` вызывается в том же потоке.

Добавьте в класс вашей основной формы два поля:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer;
Form3 formButton;
```

И обработчик события таймера:

```
private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Opacity > 0)
        this.Opacity -= 0.1;
    else if (formButton.Opacity < 1)
        formButton.Opacity += 0.1;
    else
    {
        timer.Stop();
        timer.Tick -= Timer_Tick;
    }
}
```

Теперь ваш код будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
formButton = new Form3();
formButton.Owner = this;
formButton.Show();
formButton.Opacity = 0;

timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
timer.Interval = 30;
timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
timer.Start();
```

Обратите внимание, что свойство `Opacity` формы имеет тип `double`. Поэтому я заменил точные сравнения `!= 0` и `!= 1` на `> 0` и `< 1` - это связано со спецификой представления вещественных чисел - точное сравнение может не сработать.

Также обратите внимание на необходимость отписки таймера от события: `timer.Tick -= Timer_Tick;` - это необходимо, чтобы избежать утечки памяти.

При желании, таймер можно создать в дизайнере формы, задав ему необходимые свойства и события.